Checking value of Function output to if/else statement
I'm new to learning Powershell but know enough to be dangerous about some values.  That being said, I'm approaching this code line with a bit of "newness" to it, given I've never used the value "Function" before.
What I'm trying to do is take this code below and create a if/else statement that can trigger a block of code.  What I'm running into is that no matter what the value is, I still get a incorrect reading of the "True" or "False" value in the statement.  Here is what the code is:
function Test-PendingReboot
{
 if (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 try {
   $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
   $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
   if(($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending){
     return $true
     }
 }catch{}

 Return $False
 }

 Test-pendingreboot
 $PendingReboot = Test-PendingReboot

if ($PendingReboot -eq 'False') { 
   write-output "Value is False"
   }else{ 
   write-output "Value is True"
}

However, every time I try to run this command I always get the following output which is contrary to the output result.
PS C:\Windows\system32> .\testing for Install 2.ps1
True
Value is False

However, if I take the first "if" statement and say "-eq 'False'" I seem to get the same result as before, which makes me scratch my head and think I'm doing something wrong.
#Example of the code change

if ($PendingReboot -eq 'True') { 
   write-output "Value is False"
   }else{ 
        write-output "Value is True"
}

#Result
True
Value is False



This comes down to how PowerShell evaluates comparisons. It will always attempt to use the type of the left hand object. In this case your function returns $true or $false which is boolean. It then attempts to convert the string 'true' to that type, and any value that isn't null or 0 will evaluate to $true. You could put if ($PendingReboot -eq 'watermelon') and as far as PowerShell is concerned it means the same thing as if ($PendingReboot -eq 'True'). Instead use if ($PendingReboot -eq $true) or if ($PendingReboot -eq $false). Or, since the if statement is really just looking for a $true or $false itself you could do this:
if (-Not $PendingReboot) { 
   write-output "Value is False"
}else{ 
   write-output "Value is True"
}

Personally I'd use the ! shorthand for -Not and do if(!$PendingReboot){, but that's just me.

That is exactly what I needed.  Thanks for clarifying that and the quick response to my inquiry!  Much appreciated!
